# Azure websites ftp upload fails on some files but not others

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-roles

I've tried uploading an ASP.Net MVC site to an Azure website account and I'm running into a serious problem. Most files will transfer fine but a few will ALWAYS fail.The trouble is that it is always the same files that fail and I cannot figure out why. I've tried deploying from Visual Studio using FTP and the "Web Deploy" methods and I've tried using FTP and FTPS via FileZilla and have the same issue.  What might I be doing wrong???

Here's a FileZilla log of the errors I'm seeing.

```
Status: Resolving address of waws-prod-blu-003.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net
Status: Connecting to 137.117.88.16:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command:    USER xxxxx\xxxxxxxx
Response:   331 Password required
Command:    PASS *********
Response:   230 User logged in.
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
Status: Connected
Status: Starting upload of C:\websites\HSDeploy\css\bootstrap.min.css
Command:    CWD /site/wwwroot/css
Response:   250 CWD command successful.
Command:    TYPE A
Response:   200 Type set to A.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (137,117,88,16,39,138).
Command:    STOR bootstrap.min.css
Response:   550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. 
Error:  Critical file transfer error
```

This is just an example of one of the files that is failing. Is this a bug in Windows Azure Websites or am I doing something wrong? It seems to me that this is a critical problem and major barrier to getting a site working on Azure. :-(

Comment: did you find this?  Seems odd the same files keep failing.  I tried replacing MS FTP service with U-Serv and it is the same files that fail.

Comment: I have the same issue when trying to 'put' files to a remote server via dreamweaver and get the same issue in filezilla.

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like a time-out issue on the server.  You will need to tell your FTP client to keep the connection alive so that it doesn't start a second connection while the first connection is still trying to upload the files.

To set this in FileZilla client, go to Edit, Settings, Connection, FTP, and check "Send FTP keep-alive commands" checkbox.

For more detailed explanation of the problem, visit: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wats/archive/2013/12/13/setting-up-a-passive-ftp-server-in-windows-azure-vm.aspx  Scroll towards the bottom and read the "Points to consider from Azure SLB perspective" section.

I had the same problem with my FTP on Azure and checking the "Send FTP keep-alive commands" checkbox above solved my problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: worked for me when uploading to azure with filezilla as well as the bug listed below by @frikz, I had to keep trying until the lock came off

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue with Azure + FileZilla. I solved the problem by connecting to the FTP host name and not the FTPS host name.

Comment: FTP host name and FTPS host name seem to be the same value to me in Azure unless this has recently been changed.

Comment: The hostnames are the same, but the protocols are not. One starts with ftp://  and the other with ftps://

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue, but with a slightly different error message:

```
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Response:   550 The supplied message is incomplete. The signature was not verified. 
Error:  File transfer failed
```

I solved the problem by using [CuteFTP](http://www.cuteftp.com/) instead of FileZilla.

Answer (score 1):

Bug according to Microsoft Support website see link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238644

Seems the only solution is to retry until the internal lock is released.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, using FileZilla, on connection settings, General Tab, in Encryption selecting "Require implicit FTP over TLS", Solved my problem (using Protocol FTP not SFTP).

Answer (score 0):

OK, sorted it.  I was trying an Amazon Web Services machine and odd files would fail to transfer again and again, it was like it was picking on the same ones.

In my case it was my anti-virus software on the client machine that was messing it up.  AVG....